# Core Data NSmanagedObjectModel NSPersistentStoreCoordinater NSManagedObjectContext NSFetchRequest

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

Hi i am new to IOS and trying to learn core data and anyone tell me exact use of NSmanagedObjectModel

NSPersistentStoreCoordinater

NSManagedObjectContext

NSFetchRequest   and  NSEntityDescription

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Managed Object Model:** You can think of this as the database schema. It is a class that contains definitions for each of the objects (also called “Entities”) that you are storing in the database. Usually, you will use the visual editor you just peeked at to set up what objects are in the database, what their attributes, and how they relate to each other. However, you can do this with code too!

**Persistent Store Coordinator:** You can think of this as the database connection. Here’s where you set up the actual names and locations of what databases will be used to store the objects, and any time a managed object context needs to save something it goes through this single coordinator.

**Managed Object Context:** You can think of this as a “scratch pad” for objects that come from the database. It’s also the most important of the three for us, because we’ll be working with this the most. Basically, whenever you need to get objects, insert objects, or delete objects, you call methods on the managed object context

For more refer [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-tutorial-for-ios-getting-started)